# How to get the level of each node from a tree demonstrated in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, tree

I have a tree data structure demonstrated in a List as the following:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> // Key, list of children

Data(1) = { 2 } // root
Data(2) = { 3 }
Data(3) = { 4, 5 }
Data(4) = { 5 }
Data(5) = {   } // leaf
```

I wonder if you could help me with creating a dictionary of Items and levels:

`Dictioanry<ItemID, Level>`

Comment: List only supports a single generic parameter (and you have 2). Can you post some real c#?  I don't understand your pseudocode.

Comment: @agent-j: Sorry, it's a dictionary of (Key, Children)

Comment: That's better.  Now, do you mean level=depth? So do you want a dictionary like this? {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, }?  The 3 has 2 children (4 and 5).  4 also has a child of 5?  So what level would 5 have?  4 /and/ 5?

Comment: @ agent-j : You're right, yes the depth. Actually the max value.

Comment: I think a `Dictionary<ParentNode,ChildNode>` and the tree hasn't max value every node/leaf in the tree has its depth,parent,and children nodes except root node hasn't parent

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it is the best solution, but should work:

```
        var data = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        data[1] = new List<int> { 2 };
        data[2] = new List<int> { 3 };
        data[3] = new List<int> { 4, 5 };
        data[4] = null;
        data[5] = new List<int> { 6, 7 };
        data[6] = new List<int> { 8 };
        data[7] = null;
        data[8] = null;

        var allparents = new Dictionary<int, int>(data.Count);

        foreach (var node in data) {
            if (node.Value != null) {
                foreach (var child in node.Value) {
                    allparents[child] = node.Key;
                }
            }
        }

        int root = data.Keys.Except(allparents.Keys).First();
        int maxdepth = 1;
        foreach (int child in allparents.Keys) {
            int depth = 1;
            int parent = child;
            while (parent != root) {
                ++depth;
                parent = allparents[parent];
            }
            if (depth > maxdepth) {
                maxdepth = depth;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(maxdepth);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you used this [node class](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/a-generic-tree-of-nodes-the-easy-way), you can simply do this:

```
nodes.All.ToDictionary(n => n.Value, n => n.Level);
```

You need to fill the tree a little different (see the info in the link)